# How to programmatically get all nodes which are related to the specific term ID?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, hooks, webforms

**What I want to do?**

I want to display all **categories** in first drop down and in second all **titles** of related nodes with the selected **category**.

To get that I have mentioned all the tasks I have done. Please read below.

**1st:** Created taxonomy named `category` with terms listed `Laptop`, `Car`, `Mobile` etc.

**2nd:** Content type named `product` with fields `title`, `description`, `category` etc. The `category` field uses **term reference** of `category` taxonomy.
 **3rd:** Created a form with [WebForm](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) with fields named `category` and `product`as drop down
 **4th:** First, `categories` drop down field, displayed all categories (Laptop, Car, Mobile) by using [WebForm Term Options](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_term_opts).
 **5th:** Second, `product` drop down field  is empty yet.

I have used [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7.x) hook to alter the webForm I created. I have found the [solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/99248/programmatically-getting-custom-node-belonging-to-a-term#answer-100205) to get all the nodes pragmatically those are related with specific taxonomy term ID.

**6th:** I have fetched term related all node by this code:

```
$arg = arg();
$query = db_select('node','n');
$query->join('taxonomy_index','ti','n.nid=ti.nid');
$query->fields('n', array('nid', 'title', 'type'))
  ->condition('n.type', 'products')
  ->condition('ti.tid', $arg['2']);
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
$dropdown_array = array('' => t('-Select-'));
foreach ($result as $nid => $node) {
    $dropdown_array[$node->title] = $node->title;
}
echo '<pre>';   print_r($dropdown_array);   echo '<pre>';
```

**My first question is how to display all these nodes' titles in existing drop down field?**

**Another question is on `category` change, `products` must be change according to its nodes like ajax?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My first question is how to display all these nodes' titles in
>   existing drop down field?

In a [custom module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules) you can define your own select option element with the following code:

```
function custom_tweaks_webform_select_options_info() {
  $items = array();

  if (function_exists('_get_products_by_termid')) {
    $items['my-products'] = array(
      'title' => t('My products'),
      'options callback' => '_get_products_by_termid',
    );
  }
  return $items;
}


function _get_products_by_termid($termids) {
  // Debug
  $termids = array(1,2,3);

  $nids = taxonomy_select_nodes($termids);
  $products = [];
  if (!empty($nids)) {
    foreach ($nids as $nid => $value) {
      $products[$value] = node_load($value)->title;
    }
  }
  return $products;
}
```

- Enable this module
- Add a **select option** element to your webform
- Edit this element and select **My products** under the **Load a pre-built option list** field (see screenshots)
- Make sure you also have a **select option** element to your webform with the categories taxonomy vocabulary given (see screenshots)

[image]
[image]
[image]

To answer your second question

> Another question is on category change, products must be change
>   according to its nodes like ajax?

replace the custom code from above with the code below. Still needs default value set and checking for empty values but it should point you in the right direction. The thing is that you ajaxify the category field (bij setting the #ajax property on it) and provide your own products field and fill that with values based on the term id from the categories field.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function custom_tweaks_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_41') {
    $form['submitted']['categories']['#ajax'] = array(
        'callback' => '_show_products_based_on_category_term',
        'wrapper' => 'products-div',
        'method' => 'replace',
        'effect' => 'fade',
    );

    $term_id = $form_state['values']['submitted']['categories'];
    $tid = substr($term_id, 4);

    $form['submitted']['products'] = array(
      '#title' => 'Products',
      '#type'     => 'radios',
      '#weight'  => '2',
      '#options'  => _get_products_by_termid(array($tid)),
      '#prefix' => '<div id="products-div">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
  }
}


function _show_products_based_on_category_term($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['submitted']['products'];
}

function _get_products_by_termid($termids) {
  $nids = taxonomy_select_nodes($termids);
  $products = [];
  if (!empty($nids)) {
    foreach ($nids as $nid => $value) {
      $products[$value] = node_load($value)->title;
    }
  }
  return $products;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Your solution isn't working for me. However I have updated this question Please check the point number **6**.

Comment: Ah probably you didn't get ant results because no termid was given to the function `_get_products_by_termid`. I updated the code and added screenshots of how your webform fields should look

Comment: Thanks for the great solution... It works as I expected. I'm learning good with you all .Thanks again...

Comment: Glad it worked. For your other question, *show products based on selected term*, you have to ajaxify the form elements. See [http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/54362/8606 ] and [https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/ajax-forms-in-drupal-7]  for examples. Short on time now but can help later on.

Comment: look at my edit. I added the second answer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/225855/revisions

Comment: Thanks @undersound for your help and time. However, it doesn't work for me but got a lot of things and ideas from this revisions. you really taught me unexpectedly with you simple examples.
I added join queries in my module with the help of yours above examples. Now I have only one issue. [Here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226692/how-to-get-selected-term-id-from-drop-down-while-ajaxing)

Answer (score 0):

1) Have you looked at the Hierarchical Select module? https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select

Comment: Yeah, I have already looked. But most importantly have to use `webForm` module it provides user to send email his message. So, I have no reason to use `Hierarchical Select` module.