# How to get selected term ID from drop down while ajaxing?

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I can't get name or ID from selected drop down during ajaxing. I was trying with code below:

```
if(isset($form_state['values']['submitted']['company_name'])){
    $company_ID = $form_state['values']['submitted']['company_name'];
    $form['submitted']['company_name']['#value'] = $company_ID;
}
```

Why is `$company_ID` empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasted too much time on this tiny task. However, I have done what I wanted.

Actually, I had to add `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;` in my `callback_function`.

```
if(isset($form_state['values']['submitted']['company_name'])){
    $array_id[0] = $form_state['input']['company_name']; //$form_state['input']['company_name'] array holding the number I wanted.
    $company_ID = $array_id[0];
    $form['submitted']['company_name']['#value'] = $company_ID;
}
```

Comment: glad you got it worked out